# Angular2-multiselect-dropdown onClose event fires incorrectly

Tags: angular

I am using [angular2-multiselect-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown): "^4.2.6" and the onClose event is not working as expected. Please understand the below scenario and also refer the link below for more details on the issue.

After I close the dropdown, the onClose method is called. Expected :)
But After this, if I click anywhere on the page, it calls the onClose method. weird and not expected :(

Kindly provide the resolution for this as I need to use the onClose method critically.

Please Refer the below stackblitz for it

[Reproduction of Issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i4myym)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by the developers in the version 4.2.7.